# DynamoDB: Query on GSI (Global secondary index) does not return data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using the Serverless framework to setup the below table:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: ap-southeast-1
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: "Itinerary-${self:provider.stage}"
    DYNAMODB_COUNTRY_INDEX: country_index
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}/index/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_COUNTRY_INDEX}"
resources:
  Resources:
    ItineraryTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: ID
            AttributeType: S
          -
            AttributeName: Country
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: ID
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          -
            IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_COUNTRY_INDEX}
            KeySchema:
              -
                AttributeName: Country
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

Now, I am able to get to do a "get" to retrieve items from the DB by ID. However, if I try to do a "query" on the GSI, it returns nothing. There is no failure, but I never get data back.

The below is what my query looks like:

```
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE, // maps back to the serverless config variable above
    IndexName: process.env.DYNAMODB_COUNTRY_INDEX, // maps back to the serverless config variable above
    KeyConditionExpression: "Country=:con",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":con" : "Portugal" }
};

dynamoDb.query(params, (error, result) => {
    // handle potential errors
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
            body: 'Couldn\'t fetch the Itineraries'+error,
        });
        return;
    }
}

var json_result = JSON.stringify(result.Item);
```

I should add here that I can't get data if I do a filterless "scan" as well. If I try to search for items by index (or otherwise) on the AWS Dynamo web portal, I get results though.

I cannot figure out what it is that's going wrong here. Any light that someone can shed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that country is stored with same case (i.e. camel case with upper case P) as you mentioned in express attribute values?

Comment: Can you perform the query and get results using the AWS Console?

Comment: @notionquest: The case seems fine. The item in question is stored as "Country": "Portugal" in the database.

Comment: @StevenS.: Yes, if I go to the console, and select Query against Index, and then just search for the Country, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you please run "aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name Itinerary-Dev" and check the IndexStatus and backfilling status? Please update the OP with describe table output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the problem. There was a key statement missing in the question that I posted (because I thought it wasn't relevant), but which turned out to the problem.

I was just stringifying the results from the query using:

```
var json_result = JSON.stringify(result.Item);
```

The above works for a "get", but for a query, it needs to be result.Item**s**:

```
var json_result = JSON.stringify(result.Items);
```

Silly on my part. Thank you for the help!

P.S. I have added the statement to the original question to be clear